# Classic Asp session state lost when navigating from .aspx to .asp page

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, load-balancing

We have a legacy application that is a mixture of `Classic Asp` and `ASP.NET`.  This legacy app is in a sub folder of our main ASP.NET web site.  To be clear in this sub folder there is a mixture of .asp and .aspx pages.

We don't share session but when navigating to an .aspx page from .asp we post enough information in the body to setup session in `ASP.NET`.

If the user navigates back to the .asp page then the users session is still there and everything works as normal on a single web server.

We are testing `load balancing` on two web servers, the setup is as follows.

The main `ASP.NET` uses no affinity, so it's up to the load balancer to decide which web server to use.  The legacy app is in a sub folder, this sub folder has single affinity.  Both web servers have the same machine key setup in the web.config.  Session state for the `ASP.NET` application is stored in the database.

The issue is that the `Classic Asp` session is lost when navigating back to .asp from .aspx. I would like to understand why?

Note. Single affinity - sticky sessions is working for the legacy folder, I've checked this using the IIS logs.  So all requests to the legacy folder will always be routed to the same web server.

Answer (score 0):

Classic ASP doesn't support sessions across servers in a load-balanced scenario. Using ASP.NET terminology (loosely), the only `mode`s supported by ASP Clasic sessions are `InProc` and `Off`.

If you want session to work in a load balanced scenario you either have to configure your load balancer to use "sticky sessions/affinity", or roll your own custom session management backed by a database or something else (which is tricky to get right without creating security vulnerabilities).

Reading material: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972338.aspx

Comment: I understand this, which is why affinity is setup for the legacy folder so all requests are routed to the same server based on IP.

Comment: Ah, I see. The way I've seen affinity implemented by load balancers is that they add a header or cookie to the responses; the load balancer uses that tag to track which server to use when they get the next request. My guess is that when you go to the ASP.NET pages, the header/cookie is dropped by the load balancer (because the session is not affine anymore, so it must stop tracking). Can you use Fiddler or a similar tool to check for load balancer headers/cookies, and verify this idea? If this is correct, check with your load balancer vendor to see if they have any workaround.

Comment: The load balancer is using the IP or rather the first 3 octets of the IP to route traffic to the same server.  The ASP.NET pages for the legacy app are in the same folder as the Classic asp page, so affinity is still required.  I've confirmed using the IIS logs that all requests to the legacy folder, asp or aspx are hitting the same server.